# How to create an application specific effective exception Hierarchy

Tags: java, exception

I am a newbie with designing stuff though I have some experience as a developer. My question is related to the statement -

"It is always a good practice to design the exception hierarchy at the start of the project"

After much of reading and researching the definition of a checked and unchecked exception is well clear.

However, I still wonder what is the best practices in designing the exception hierarchy for an application. Is the below approach right?

1. Create your own application specific top level exceptions

   - MyAppRuntimeException
   - MyAppCheckedException
2. Subclass MyAppCheckedException with all your business exceptions where you want the caller to take a specific exception. For example

   - TryWithADifferentInputException - This is not the right input, correct it
   - TryAlternateServiceException - This service is not available, but you can choose another service that will do the job
3. Similarly subclass your runtime exception which spiral up and are captured only by something like the spring exception resolver and display appropriate message on front end.

Another thing that bugs me is how to come up with most of the exception scenarios at the start of the project. What should be the strategy to do so.

Comment: Just a comment, I wouldn't name the exceptions 'what the user should do instead', but what the exception is. Example - instead of "TryWithADifferentInputException", perhaps "InputTypeException" (The type of input is not correct) and "TryAlternateServiceException" as "ServiceUnavailableException". :)

Comment: Thanks Stu Whyte.. I wanted to give the impression as an example where the caller needs to take some action. However I definitely agree that the name should be for the cause and not the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello hailMurphy and welcome to SO!

IMO, it is *not* necessary to design an entire exception hierarchy for every app. Rather, you should only introduce new exceptions if none of the existing stock ones adequately address the error you're encountering.

Your TryWithADifferentInputException for instance could probably easily be replaced with an `IllegalArgumentException` or possibly `IllegalStateException`. I find that 99% of the time, I'm well able to do with the existing ones.

As for knowing which exceptions to expect before you actually start writing code: The complex parts of your program, such as class structure, algorithms, protocols, etc. should be thought out and documented before you actually fire up your IDE and get hands-on. UML is a common way to do this. During that process, as you're pen-and-papering your algorithm or protocol, try looking at border cases (what happens when this value becomes zero? What if this argument is `null`? Will my algorithm still work? Good! Will it break? Exception!) and playing devil's advocate (what if the network connection breaks down halfway through my protocol? Can I recover from this, or does it leave me in an unrecoverable state?) you should be able to see exception scenarios.

If you do find yourself in need for creating custom exceptions, derive them directly from whichever ancestor seems most fit - Error, IllegalStateException, RuntimeException, IOException, etc. Don't create your own complete hierarchy unless there is a scenario where you need to *only* catch all of your own exceptions and none of the stock ones. Honestly, though, I can't see a scenario where that might be useful.

On a more general note, exceptions should be a "last resort" to deal with errors that can't be otherwise recovered from, and not as a form of control flow. If you're expecting something to happen naturally as part of your application (such as bad user input), you should generally not deal with it through exceptions. If you have an algorithm that breaks unrecoverably in a lot of cases, it can be an indication that you haven't found the right one yet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not going to answer all of your questions, but just the parts that I know based in my experience.

The idea of create the exceptions at the begining just have sense if we have the design of the app really clear. I mean, we have to know the flows of the app and what could happen. If we dont know the design more than 80% probably we will change many things, including exceptions hierachy, many times.

Furthermore, If our app is designed correctly and at the coding stage a new exception appears, should be easy the addition in the exceptions tree.

Well I hope be clear for you. 
Bye